# How to use Notification based Invalidation in AppFabric

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

I will be using AppFabric caching for an application we are going to build. 
We will be maintaining two different caches using the technology. 
So there should be proper communication if something happens in one or the other cache.

I have read about notification based caching which notifies on adding, removing or replacing items or regions. I have also tried the same and it is working fine.

What i am looking for is How to notify on Cache Invalidation. ?
Read from MSDN that there are two ways for invalidation cache - 1. TimeOut based and 2. Notification based.
I am looking for some same codes for the same.

Can any one help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way of notification which helps invalidation in the main cache. However, the same are available for local cache invalidation.